# Error trying to deploy a contract that requires a token in the constructor

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I have a contract (Factory) that needs to store and interact with a ERC20PresetMinterPauser token but I get an error when i try to deploy it. :

How can I deploy my factory contract?

this is the error:

```bash
  1) addMintRequest test
       should add a mint request:
     Error: invalid ENS name (argument="name", value="<SignerWithAddress 0x3b8486Cc119fB849DC5Dbf92dDe42f703E1Ae036>", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=providers/5.0.21)
      at Logger.makeError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:205:28)
      at Logger.throwError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:217:20)
      at Logger.throwArgumentError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:221:21)
      at EthersProviderWrapper.<anonymous> (node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/src.ts/base-provider.ts:1365:20)
      at step (node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/base-provider.js:46:23)
      at Object.next (node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/base-provider.js:27:53)
      at fulfilled (node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/base-provider.js:18:58)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

contract code (constructor)

```
contract Factory is Ownable, AccessControl {

  ERC20PresetMinterPauser public token;

  bytes32 public constant CUSTODIAN_ROLE = keccak256("CUSTODIAN_ROLE");
  bytes32 public constant MERCHANT_ROLE = keccak256("MERCHANT_ROLE");

  enum RequestStatus {PENDING, CANCELED, APPROVED, REJECTED}

  mapping(bytes32=>uint) public mintRequestNonce;

  // requests
  Request[] public mintRequests;
  Request[] public burnRequest;

  struct Request {
    address requester;
    uint amount;
    address depositAddress;
    string txid;
    uint nonce;
    uint timestamp;
    RequestStatus status;
  }

  constructor(address custodian, address merchant, address _token) {
    _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);

    _setupRole(CUSTODIAN_ROLE, custodian);
    _setupRole(MERCHANT_ROLE, merchant);

    token = ERC20PresetMinterPauser(_token);
  }
//...
```

test:

```js
const {expect} = require("chai");
describe("addMintRequest test", function () {
  it("should add a mint request", async function () {
    const GCLP = await ethers.getContractFactory("GCLP");
    const Factory = await ethers.getContractFactory("Factory");
    const token = await GCLP.deploy();

    [owner, merchant, custodian, acct1] = await ethers.getSigners();

    await token.deployed();

    console.log(token.interface);
    const factory = await Factory.deploy(custodian.address, merchant.address, token.address);

    await factory.deployed();

    expect(await factory.addMintRequest(1000, "txid", acct1)).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

instead of token.address in the arguments i have tried only 'token' 'token.instance' etc...

Comment: this error is saying that the address is not registered in ENS (Ethereum Name System) , the contract is probably checking if the address is registered in ENS

Comment: how can I register the address of the token in ENS?

Comment: you have to create an auction and buy a name for yourself. ENS is not for tokens

Comment: this is weird , why i need to do that to deploy a contract, also it is in the local testnet. I just want to pass an address of a token. why isnt allowed, im checking the API (ethers.js) and says nothing about it

Comment: it looks like it is checking the address of the Signer in the ENS, not the address of the token

Comment: whos address is this? 0x3b8486Cc119fB849DC5Dbf92dDe42f703E1Ae036

Comment: is the address of the token contract , my factory contract requires it, but i dont know how to pass it to it.

Comment: not it is not. contracts can't sign , they don't have private keys. It is somebody's EOA

Comment: I think the problem is in the last line, where you are using `acct1` instead of `acct1.address1`